# How can I add every element with the second and 3rd element after it in a grid (2D array)?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have a 2D array and I'm trying to add element `x` to the two next elements in the grid horizontally while not going out of bounds.

For instance,

if this is my grid,

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I want an output array that looks like

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

because every element is added with the next 2 elements after it.

Here had been my attempt so far:

```
        int n = 2;
        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++ ) {
            for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++){
                for(int j = x+1; j <= x + n && j < array.length; j++ ){
                l.add(array[x][y] + array[x + j][y]);
            }
```

However, when I try to run this, I get an index out of bound exception. I've tried to change the parameters of each variable but to no avail. What should I change in this?

Comment: If you are at the last cell of the first row, i.e. `array[0][5]` in your example, which cells are added to 0,5? 1,0 and 1,1?

Comment: It would return the same number, since there is no element to the right of it within that horizontal array left to add

Comment: Then why aren't the first numbers in your array `[3, 3, 3, 2, 1, ...`?

Comment: oh my bad, I explained wrong. If it's the last element or if the index of the element does not have upto 2 elements ahead of it, I want it to add the previous 2 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the array and add the current value with the next two values if the current index is not the last index.

Assuming you have a 2D array of ints called "grid", you could do something like this:

```java
int[][] newGrid = new int[grid.length][grid[0].length];
for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
        if (j < grid[0].length - 2) {
            newGrid[i][j] = grid[i][j] + grid[i][j + 1] + grid[i][j + 2];
        } else {
            newGrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, thank u for your response. Can u please specify what area should be changed again?

Comment: because from what I'm seeing, I believe it is the same code as the one I provided in my question. Not sure if I'm seeing any changes here or something

Comment: @Droid Apologies, writing mistake, check now